# Symfony 3.4 migration - How to add bundle services? AppExtension vs. config.yml vs. services.yml

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. The way how the bundle services are imported are different in these Symfony versions and I wonder what are the pros and cons of the different approaches.

The existing project was build using different bundles where each bundles has its own `XYBundle\Resources\services.yml` file and the `XYBundle\DependencyInjection\XYExtension.php` file is used to add the service config to the container:

```
class XYExtension extends Extension {   
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

This way the services defined in `XYBundle\Resources\services.yml` become available within the project.

When creating a new Bundle in `Symfony 3.4` no extension is created. Instead the `services.yml` is added to the apps `config.yml`

```
// app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@XYBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

However, the `AppBundle` which was created with the `Symfony 3.4` skeleton does not have a `services.yml` file at all. Instead all classes within this bundle are automatically made available as service using **autowire** and **autoconfigure** within the `app/config/services.yml` file.

I am aware that **autowire** was added in `Symfony 3.3` and that it is a great way to automatically add services and add parameters to them. This it is obvious that no `XYBundle\Resources\services.yml` file is needed any more when autowire is used.

**However, is there any difference in using the "old" extension-way to add/import the bundle `services.yml` file and the new way with importing it in `app/config/config.yml`?**

Comment: There is basically no difference between the two approaches.  If you look at the FrameworkBundle then it still uses the extension to load services even in 4.x.  If your new bundle is intended to be shared across multiple apps then use an extension to avoid the need for each app to to have to explicitly import it.  If the bundle is strictly for one app then using an import statements saves you from having to create an extension.

Comment: And while a bit off topic, you might create a new 3.4 project using the Flex installer and observe the new directory structure.  The app directory goes away.  Using the new structure will make it easier to move to S4 sometime in the future.